# for each counter loop in c++ doesn't increment with certain numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, foreach, counter

I'm working on a program that uses the for each loop to sort through an array. I was messing around with the for each loop to kind of refresh my memory on it, and I ran into a problem that's interesting. This is my code here,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int arr [4] = {5, 9, 23, 45};
    int const quote = 10;
    int failed = 0;
    for each (int i in arr)
    {
        int x = arr[i];
        if (x < quote)
        {
            failed += 1;
        }
        x = 0;
    }
    cout << failed;
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that whenever one of the numbers is within one of the variable quote, it won't count it. For example, the second number in arr is 9, but for some reason it isn't counted, and x only displays "1" at runtime. I was thinking it might have something to do with the way I'm counting the loop, but I couldn't come up with any solutions. If someone could help me understand this, I would appreciate it. As I said in the beginning, I'm trying to refresh my memory on some of these things, as I haven't them in quite a while.

Comment: This doesn't look like C++; probably C++/CLI. I'm pretty sure that when you do `for each (int i in arr)`, `i` takes on the **values** of array elements, not their indices. That is, `i` is 5 on the first iteration, 9 on the second and so on. `arr[i]` then indexes out of bounds and reads some random garbage.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that I am working with a fixed number of values for my project, so I'm just gonna use the regular for loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

this page may help you .. you can use the build in function for most  sort algorithm

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort